# How to delete data from Firebase using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a ToDo app in Swift, I am using Firebase to save data for my Swift App, but I can't delete it from collection, which called "tasks", only cells from Table View are deleting. I use Swift 5 and Xcode 12.5.1

Any help is welcome.

```
class ToDoViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
      
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var statusCheckBox: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var bodyTextField: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var blurView: UIVisualEffectView!
    @IBOutlet var popupView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    var tasks: [Task] = []
    
// Getting number of existing tasks
extension ToDoViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tasks.count
    }
    
    // Creating tasks from reusable cell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.FStore.reusableCell, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = tasks[indexPath.row].title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = tasks[indexPath.row].body
        if tasks[indexPath.row].status {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
        }
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard editingStyle == .delete else { return }
        tasks.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

        // here I need to delete data from Firebase
    }
}
```

Comment: Firebase...  Which service are you referring to?

Comment: I use Cloud Firestore

Comment: You shared quite a lot of code. When you set breakpoints in that code, and run in a debugger, which is the first line of the code that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: The problem is that in documentation you need pass the id of document to delete it and I don't understand how to retrieve it. I need implement this functionality at the end of code, the last function